# Another nesting question

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a function `F[i_Integer,B_List,l_list]` which spits out a list `{B',l'}` where `B'` and `l'` are of the same dimension as `B` and `l`, respectively. Now I want to get `F[j,B',l']` and I then want to use the output of that again to get `F[k,B'',l'']`, etc. (note that the integer argument changes at each step). What is the best way to do this? I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: I guess I can define my function as `F[{B_List,l_List},i_Integer]` and then do `Fold[F,{B,l},{i,j,k}]` but is defining a function which takes as an argument a list of lists a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
F[i_Integer, B_List, l_List] := {B - i, l + i}

B = Array[b, 3]; l = Array[L, 4];
SeedRandom[123]; {i, j, k} = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, 3]

(* {2, -1, 5} *)

Fold[F[#2, Sequence @@ #1] &, {B, l}, {i, j, k}]

(* {{-6 + b[1], -6 + b[2], -6 + b[3]}, {6 + L[1], 6 + L[2], 6 + L[3], 
  6 + L[4]}} *)
```

Comment: This is very nice, thanks!